# How to remove or suppress AWS console message?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

Recently, this started to show up in the console:

```
(node:2924) NOTE: We are formalizing our plans to enter AWS SDK for JavaScript (v2) into maintenance mode in 2023.

Please migrate your code to use AWS SDK for JavaScript (v3).
For more information, check the migration guide at https://a.co/7PzMCcy
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
```

My first response was, "OMG! Software can be out of date? I didn't know! Thank you AWS for telling met that!"

But now that I've been informed that software gets updated how do I remove or suppress this message? (yes I'll make updates in due time)

The message contains a message, "Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created" and so I tried `node --trace-warnings` in terminal and get this:

```
Welcome to Node.js v18.12.1.
Type ".help" for more information.
> .help
.break    Sometimes you get stuck, this gets you out
.clear    Alias for .break
.editor   Enter editor mode
.exit     Exit the REPL
.help     Print this help message
.load     Load JS from a file into the REPL session
.save     Save all evaluated commands in this REPL session to a file

Press Ctrl+C to abort current expression, Ctrl+D to exit the REPL
```

That doesn't help any. Having said this I do appreciate the AWS team and library and effort.

Comment: You might want to check this GitHub issue: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/4354

Comment: @ArpitJain So that conversation started in Feb, "et304383 commented on Feb 27". So why is it showing up now? The AWS team also recognized it's not the best place to inform developers of an update. But if it's showing up now does that mean they haven't found a better way to inform developers?

Answer (score 1):

From the [related github issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/4354#issuecomment-1454016910)

```
require('aws-sdk/lib/maintenance_mode_message').suppress = true
```

or via an environment variable

```
AWS_SDK_JS_SUPPRESS_MAINTENANCE_MODE_MESSAGE=1 node the-thing.js
```